# Como ordenar con insert sort una lista enlazada c++

Tags: c++

Tengo un programa en **c++** en el cual quiero manejar el método de ordenamiento **InsertSort**.

Pido los datos con un case en el archivo main.cpp para después en el archivo Lista.cpp poder indicarle donde insertarlo, en este caso tengo el **insertaInicio.**

```
case 1:
        cout << "Codigo: ";
        cin >> codigoDistribuidora;
        nuevo.guardaNombre(codigoDistribuidora);
        cout << "Nombre: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, nombreDistribuidora);
        nuevo.guardaNombre(nombreDistribuidora);
        cout << "Domicilio: ";
        getline(cin, domicilioDistribuidora);
        nuevo.guardaNombre(domicilioDistribuidora);
        cout << "Telefono: ";
        cin >> telefonoDistribuidora;
        nuevo.guardaNombre(telefonoDistribuidora);
        cout << "Nombre del gerente: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, nombreGerente);
        nuevo.guardaNombre(nombreGerente);
        l.insertaInicio(nuevo);
        break;
```

y el inserta inicio es este:

```
void Lista::insertaInicio(Distribuidora dato) {
Nodo *tmp = new Nodo;
Nodo *aux = inicio;
tmp->guardaObjeto(dato);

tmp->guardaNodoSig(NULL);

bool nada = vacia();
if (nada) {
    inicio = tmp;
}
else {
    tmp->sig = aux;
    inicio = tmp;
}
string nombreDistribuidora = dato.damenombreDistribuidora();
string codigoDistribuidora = dato.damecodigoDistribuidora();
cout << "Has agregado la Distruibuidora con el nombre: '" << nombreDistribuidora << "' y codigo '" << codigoDistribuidora << "'" << endl;
}
```

Como seria una forma de usar **InsertSort** y que los vaya ordenando al momento de que los vas insertando. Espero me de a entender gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case 1:
    cout << "Codigo: ";
    cin >> codigoDistribuidora;
    nuevo.guardaNombre(codigoDistribuidora);
    cout << "Nombre: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, nombreDistribuidora);
    nuevo.guardaNombre(nombreDistribuidora);
    cout << "Domicilio: ";
    getline(cin, domicilioDistribuidora);
    nuevo.guardaNombre(domicilioDistribuidora);
    cout << "Telefono: ";
    cin >> telefonoDistribuidora;
    nuevo.guardaNombre(telefonoDistribuidora);
    cout << "Nombre del gerente: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, nombreGerente);
    nuevo.guardaNombre(nombreGerente);
    l.insertaInicio(nuevo);
    break;
```

El código anterior debería ir en una función independiente. Aparte de mejorar enormemente la legibilidad del código hay que tener en cuenta que las sentencias `switch` pueden ser bastante peligrosas si desaparece un `break` o si éste se cuela antes de tiempo. Es altamente recomendable tener `case` lo más sencillos posible.

Por otro lado, y dado que no incluyes la implementación completa de `Lista`, te comento que en la función `insertaInicio` puedes tener un problema:

```
void Lista::insertaInicio(Distribuidora dato) {
  Nodo *tmp = new Nodo;
  Nodo *aux = inicio; // <<--- AQUI!!!
}
```

¿Qué sucede si la lista está vacía y, en consecuencia, `inicio` apunta a `nullptr`? Dado que estás haciendo una copia de `inicio` en `aux` no vale modificar la dirección apuntada por `aux`, ya que en ese caso `inicio` no se va a enterar.

Y bueno, hablando ya de tu problema, lo que tienes que hacer es encontrar en qué punto de la lista has de insertar al nuevo elemento. De esta forma la lista estará SIEMPRE ordenada. Lo que te falta es determinar la forma de ordenar la lista:

- ¿Por código de distribuidora?
- ¿Por nombre de distribuidora?
- ¿Por el número de teléfono?

Si asumimos que eliges la primera opción el algoritmo y que el orden es creciente, para determinar la posición del nuevo elemento sería la siguiente:

1. Si `inicio` es `nullptr` la lista está vacía, luego `inicio` apunta al nuevo elemento y hemos terminado
2. En caso contrario recorrer los elementos de la lista hasta encontrar un código que sea mayor que el del elemento a añadir. El nuevo elemento tendrá que insertarse entre ese nodo y el anterior.

Dicho con código podría ser algo tal que así:

```
Nodo* nuevo = new Nodo;
// falta la inicialización del nodo

if( inicio == nullptr )
  inicio = nuevo;
else
{
  Nodo* previo = inicio;

  Nodo* siguiente = inicio->sig;

  while ( siguiente != nullptr && siguiente->damecodigoDistribuidora() < nuevo->damecodigoDistribuidora() )
  {
    previo = siguiente;
    siguiente = previo->sig;
  }

  // Podemos llegar a este punto desde dos caminos diferentes
  // 1. El código de siguiente es mayor que el del nuevo elemento
  // 2. Hemos llegado al final de la lista
  // En cualquier caso la operativa es exactamente la misma:
  // Insertar el nodo entre previo y siguiente
  previo->sig = nodo;
  nodo->sig = siguiente;
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Lo que pasa que aux lo uso en lugar de usar inicio, unicamente lo tengo declarado asi por que el profesor que nos pide eso asi es como nos lo pidio en si la lista funciona correctamente. unicamente el metodo de ordenamiento no tenia idea de como poder insertarlo. Gracias por tu respuesta. 

Quiero ordenarlo por codigo esa parte me falto incluirla.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer estás trabajando con una [lista simplemente enlazada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_enlazada#Listas_simples_enlazadas) lo cual hace el proceso de inserción ordenada ligeramente más complicado.

En este tipo de listas, el proceso de inserción ordenado se divide en:

1. **Localizar el punto de inserción**: recorre los nodos desde tu raíz hasta el último nodo (tope) comparando el valor de entrada con el almacenado; en el momento en que el valor de entrada sea menor al almacenado (o hayas alcanzado el tope) habrás encontrado el punto de inserción.
2. **Crear el nuevo nodo**: debes enlazarlo al nodo del punto de inserción (el primero que contiene un valor mayor al de entrada o el tope).
3. **Re-enlazar los nodos**: el nodo anterior al punto de inserción debe apuntar al nuevo nodo creado.

---

```
Nodo *anterior = inicio;
Nodo *punto_insercion = anterior->sig;

while (punto_insercion  && (punto_insercion->dato > dato))
{
    anterior = punto_insercion;
    punto_insercion = punto_insercion->sig;
}

// Una vez superado el bucle, punto_insercion apunta
// al nodo inmediatamente superior al actual o al tope

anterior->sig = new Nodo(dato, punto_insercion);
```

En el código de ejemplo anterior estoy asumiendo:

- La lista no está vacía.
- `Nodo` dispone de un constructor que recibe `dato` y el nodo al que apuntar .
- El `dato` a comparar dispone de un operador mayor-que `>`.

Ten en cuenta que lo que he escrito es una guía, debes adaptarlo a tus necesidades y tener en cuenta que no he probado el pseudo-código