# ¡Ayuda! Error <Segmentation fault> con lista simple C++

Tags: c++

Saludos a todos, me estreno en esta maravillosa página con un bloque de código que continuamente hace saltar error de "Segmentation fault" y no sé el porqué.

El código debe recibir un entero, crear un nodo con dicho entero y luego insertarlo en la lista manteniendo un orden creciente.

Cuando está el caso de que el nodo se agrega antes del primer término funciona bien, pero cuando debo agregarlo luego del primero continuamente me salta el error.

El código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class nodo{
private:
    int edad;
    nodo *siguiente;
public:
    nodo (int N, nodo *sig=NULL){
        edad=N;
        siguiente=sig;
    };
    friend class lista;         
};

class lista{
private:
    nodo *primero;
    nodo *actual;
public:
    lista (){
        primero=NULL;
        actual=NULL;
    }
    bool listaVacia(){
        return (primero==NULL);
    }
    void insertar(int N){
        nodo *nuevo=new nodo(N);nodo *aux=primero; actual=primero;
        bool k=0;
        int i=0;
        if (listaVacia()){
            primero=nuevo;
        }else{
            while(actual || k==0){
                if(actual->edad>N){
                    nuevo->siguiente=actual;
                    if (i==0) primero=nuevo;
                    k=1;
                }else if (i==0){
                    actual=actual->siguiente;
                }else{
                    actual=actual->siguiente;
                    aux=aux->siguiente;
                }
                    i++;
            }
            if (k==0){
                actual=aux;
                actual->siguiente=nuevo;
            } 
        }
    }

        void mostrar(){
        nodo *tmp=primero;
            while(tmp){ 
                cout<<tmp->edad<<"--->";
                tmp=tmp->siguiente;
            }
            cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Por otro lado, el main es así de simple:

```
int main() {
    lista newlista; 
    int A;
    cout<<"Ingrese primera edad"<<endl;
    cin>>A;
    newlista.insertar(A);
    newlista.mostrar();
    cout<<"ingrese  otra edad"<<endl;
    cin>>A;
    newlista.insertar(A);
    newlista.mostrar();
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué la *referencia circular* de `nodo` a `lista` y viceversa?

Comment: ¿De cuál referencia circular me hablas?

Comment: La lista contiene dos `nodo` y un `nodo` contiene una `lista`, ¿O no?

Comment: Lo dices por el friend class?  Eso lo hice para poder acceder a los atributos nada más, al menos era mi intención

Comment: Ahora entiendo :P (Escribiendo respuesta)

Comment: jajaja la espero!

Answer (score 4):

> Cuando está el caso de que el nodo se agrega antes del primer término funciona bien, pero **cuando debo agregarlo luego del primero continuamente me salta el error**.

Parece un caso perfecto para usar un [depurador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depurador) paso por paso, sería una buena manera de practicar :)

---

El problema lo tienes localizado, así que vamos a depurar la función `insertar` en segunda llamada para un `N` mayor al contenido en `actual->edad`:

```
void insertar(int N){
    nodo *nuevo=new nodo(N);nodo *aux=primero; actual=primero;
    bool k=0;
    int i=0;
    if (listaVacia()){
        primero=nuevo;
    }else{
        while(actual || k==0){
            if(actual->edad>N){
                nuevo->siguiente=actual;
                if (i==0) primero=nuevo;
                k=1;
            }else if (i==0){
                actual=actual->siguiente;
            }else{
                actual=actual->siguiente;
                aux=aux->siguiente;
            }
                i++;
        }
        if (k==0){
            actual=aux;
            actual->siguiente=nuevo;
        } 
    }
}
```

Suponiendo:

- Dirección (inventada) de `primero`: `0x00000001`.
- `primero->edad = 10`.
- `primero->siguiente = NULL`.

Llamamos a `insertar(666)`:

1. Valores iniciales:

   - `nuevo`: `0x00000002` (Dirección inventada).

     - `nuevo->edad = 666`.
     - `nuevo->siguiente = NULL`.
   - `aux`: `0x00000001` (`primero`).

     - `aux->edad = 10`.
     - `aux->siguiente = NULL`.
   - `actual`: `0x00000001` (`primero`).

     - `actual->edad = 10`.
     - `actual->siguiente = NULL`.
   - `k = false`.
   - `i = 0`.
2. `if (listaVacia())` no se cumple, vamos a la rama `else`.
3. Comprobamos si debemos iniciar el bucle `while`:

   1. `actual` es `0x00000001`, que se considera verdadero.
   2. La expresión `k == 0` es verdadera.
   3. Verdadero o verdadero es verdadero: iniciamos el bucle.
4. Evaluamos `if(actual->edad>N)`:

   1. `actual->edad` es `10`.
   2. `N` es `666`.
   3. `10 > 666` es falso: vamos a la rama `else`.
5. Evaluamos `if (i==0)`:

   1. `i` es `0`.
   2. `0 == 0` es verdadero, entramos en esta rama.
6. Evaluamos `actual=actual->siguiente`:

   1. `actual` es `0x0000001`.
   2. `actual->siguiente` es `NULL`.
   3. `actual` ahora es `NULL`.
   4. Salimos del `if` actual.
7. Evaluamos `i++`:

   1. `i` ahora es `1`.
   2. Se descarta el valor de retorno.
8. Evaluamos `if (k==0)`:

   1. La expresión `k == 0` es verdadera, entramos en el `if`.
9. Evaluamos `actual=aux`:

   1. `actual` es `NULL`.
   2. `aux` es `0x0000001` (`primero`).
   3. `actual` ahora es `0x0000001` (`primero`).
10. Evaluamos `actual->siguiente=nuevo`:

    1. `actual` es `0x0000001` (`primero`).
    2. `actual->siguiente` es `NULL`.
    3. `nuevo` es `0x0000002`.
    4. `actual->siguiente` ahora es `0x0000002`.
    5. Salimos del `if` actual.
11. Finaliza el bucle, volvemos a evaluar la condición del mismo `actual || k==0`:

    1. `actual` es `0x00000001`, que se considera verdadero.
    2. La expresión `k == 0` es verdadera.
    3. Verdadero o verdadero es verdadero: iniciamos la **segunda** vuelta del bucle.
12. Evaluamos `if(actual->edad>N)`:

    1. `actual->edad` es `10`.
    2. `N` es `666`.
    3. `10 > 666` es falso: vamos a la rama `else`.
13. Evaluamos `if (i==0)`:

    1. `i` es `1`.
    2. `1 == 0` es falso, vamos a la rama `else`.
14. Evaluamos `actual=actual->siguiente`:

    1. `actual` es `0x0000001` (`primero`).
    2. `actual->siguiente` es `0x0000002`.
    3. `actual` ahora es `0x0000002`.
15. Evaluamos `aux=aux->siguiente`:

    1. `aux` es `0x0000001` (`primero`).
    2. `aux->siguiente` es `NULL`.
    3. `aux` ahora es `NULL`.
    4. Salimos del `if` actual.
16. Evaluamos `i++`:

    1. `i` ahora es `2`.
    2. Se descarta el valor de retorno.
17. Evaluamos `if (k==0)`:

    1. La expresión `k == 0` es verdadera, entramos en el `if`.
18. Evaluamos `actual=aux`:

    1. `actual` es `0x0000002` (`nuevo`).
    2. `aux` es `NULL`.
    3. `actual` ahora es `NULL`.
19. Evaluamos `actual->siguiente=nuevo`:

[image]

---

En el *paso* 19, has *saltado* (con el operador flecha `->`) desde la dirección de memoria `NULL`, esto provoca tu error ya que no puedes saltar desde `NULL` ni des-referenciar `NULL`.

Tu función `insertar` además de funcionar mal, es compleja de más, échale un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6915/2742) en que se resuelve lo que necesitas.

Comment: dsfgjksgdaskjdaweg `this == <3`. Esto es llamado, _¿Depuración a mano?_

Comment: Si, he depurado de cabeza, así que podrían haber errores, pero quería poner una seta nuclear, no me pude resistir.

Comment: +1 por generar la buena practica de programar en frio

Answer (score 3):

Bueno, en parte [Rene Garnica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17387/4499) tiene algo de razón, tu código es un poco complejo para lo que hace, he re-implementado una versión de tu código mucho más sencilla, sin la necesidad de referencias circulares y esos detalles.

En comparación con tu código, lo que buscas con la clase `lista` es acceder a los elementos de esta, lo que es practicamente innecesario, para tener un `Nodo` solo necesitas su valor y el siguiente en la pila, por lo que implementamos esta clase `Nodo`:

```
class Nodo {
    public:
        Nodo *Siguiente;
        int Valor;
        Nodo(int);
        Nodo(Nodo*);
};
```

Y su respectiva implementación:

```
// Implementación clase Nodo:
Nodo::Nodo(int a) {
    Valor = a;    // Se crea un nuevo nodo con un valor.
    Siguiente = NULL;
}
Nodo::Nodo(Nodo *n) {
    this->Valor = n->Valor;        // Se utiliza como constructor copia
    if (n->Siguiente != NULL)     
        this->Siguiente = n->Siguiente;
    else 
        this->Siguiente = NULL;
} 
// Fin implementación.
```

Así como la clase `Lista`:

```
class Lista {
    public:
        Lista();
        void Insertar(int);
        void Mostrar();
        Nodo *Nodos;
};
```

Y su implementación:

```
//Implementacion clase Lista:
Lista::Lista() {
    Nodos = NULL;
}
void Lista::Insertar(int a) {
    if (Nodos == NULL) Nodos = new Nodo(a);
    else {
        Nodos->Siguiente = new Nodo(Nodos);
        Nodos->Valor = a;
    }
}

void Lista::Mostrar() {
    Nodo *Actual = new Nodo(Nodos);

    while (Actual != NULL) {
        cout << "Actual: " << Actual->Valor << '\n';
        if (Actual->Siguiente == NULL) break;
        else
            Actual = new Nodo(Actual->Siguiente);
    }
}
```

En este `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Lista *T = new Lista(); int a = 0, count = 0, max = 0;
    cout << "Inserte la cantidad maxima de elementos a introducir: "; cin >> max;
    while (count < max) {
        cout << "Escriba el elemento "<< count + 1 << " de " << max << ": "; cin >> a;
        T->Insertar(a); // Insertamos el elemento en la lista.
        ++count;
    }
    T->Mostrar();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

El problema de `Segmentation Fault` es porque estas intentando acceder a una direccion de memoria que **no está** siendo utilizada o que ha dejado de estarlo, por lo que necesitamos preveer esto si no queremos problemas a la hora de implementar nuestra solución.

Si te fijas en el constructor de `Nodo`, hay dos constructores, la razon de esto es que no se compartan las direcciones de memoria a la hora de utilizar el puntero al objeto, sino que se cree una nueva instancia y luego reutilizar las que ya estan.

He probado este código y me ofrece el siguiente resultado:

```
Inserte la cantidad maxima de elementos a introducir: 10
Escriba el elemento 1 de 10: 1
Escriba el elemento 2 de 10: 2
Escriba el elemento 3 de 10: 3
Escriba el elemento 4 de 10: 4
Escriba el elemento 5 de 10: 523
Escriba el elemento 6 de 10: 23423
Escriba el elemento 7 de 10: 235
Escriba el elemento 8 de 10: 23
Escriba el elemento 9 de 10: 535
Escriba el elemento 10 de 10: 1234
Actual: 1234
Actual: 535
Actual: 23
Actual: 235
Actual: 23423
Actual: 523
Actual: 4
Actual: 3
Actual: 2
Actual: 1
```

Comment: Sí, si ve bastante más limpia la implementación que propones, sin embargo hecha de esa forma solo estas agregando nuevos nodos después del último que se agregó, y el problema que tengo radica en que yo no quiero eso, sino que deseo tres cosas: í) si el valor del nuevo modo es menor al valor del primer nodo, entonces este nuevo pasa a ser el primero.  II) si el nuevo nodo tiene un valor que está entre los valores de dos nodos ya creados (ej: valor a insertar:25. Tengo dos nodos con valores 20 y 30) entonces lo inserto entre ellos dos modificando los punteros debidamente y iii) añadir al final

Comment: Esto ya no forma parte de la pregunta que hiciste, es parte del ejercicio.

Comment: Jajaja de hecho sí, era mi pregunta desde el comienzo..  Quizás me expliqué mal.  Yo quise implementar mi función "insertar " pero que hiciera lo que dije arriba.

Comment: Pero, hasta ahora el problema del `Segmentation Fault` está resuelto, si buscas adaptar las reglas de tu ejercicio, puedes publicar otra pregunta, sientete libre de preguntar cualquier duda respecto a programación.

Comment: Una pequeña crítica. Si todos los miembros van a ser públicos queda más claro usar `struct` en vez de `class`.

Comment: Lo que dice @eferion tiene mucho sentido. Los `struct` son públicos por defecto, ¿Por qué no utilizarlos si sólo necesitamos atributos públicos? :)

Comment: @eferion @MiquelColl Lo he hecho un poco rapido para mostrarle al op, además de que no tengo entendido si es requerido utilizar solo `class` en el ejercicio. _(Cosas del hambre)_ :P

Comment: @NaCl intentaba ser únicamente una crítica constructiva :)

Comment: @eferion Bien recibida! Y es algo que no sabía sobre los structs.

Answer (score 0):

Hola personalmente creo que tienes un mal diseño de la lista como te comentaron no es necesario crear  referencias circulares si necesitas acceder a los atributos de la clase nodo pues dejalos públicos o implementa sus acordes getters pero no hagas cosas de mas.

En base a tu código he re-implementado la clase lista para que funcione personalmente creo es mas complicado encontrar el error que simplemente rehacer el código añadiendo que tu implementación es algo confusa.

Por ultimo te falto implementar el destructor de la clase ya que en ningún momento liberas los nodos creados.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class nodo
{
public:
    int edad;
    nodo *siguiente;

    nodo(int N)
    {
        edad=N;
        siguiente=NULL;
    };
};

class lista
{
private:
    nodo *cabeza;
public:

    lista (){
        cabeza=NULL;
    }

    //comprueba si la lista esta vacia
    bool listaVacia(){
        return (cabeza==NULL);
    }

    void insertar(int N){

        nodo *nuevo=new nodo(N);

        if(cabeza==NULL){
            cabeza=nuevo;
        }
        else{

            nodo *temp=cabeza;

            while(temp->siguiente)
            {
                temp=temp->siguiente;
            }
            temp->siguiente=nuevo;
        }
    }

    //Muestra los elementos de la lista
    void mostrar(){
        nodo *temp=cabeza;

        while(temp){
            cout<<temp->edad<<"--->";
            temp=temp->siguiente;
        }
        cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
    }


    //Destructor de la lista libera la memoria de los nodos
    ~lista(){

        while(cabeza){

            nodo *temp=cabeza;
            cabeza=cabeza->siguiente;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    lista newlista;
    int A;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese primera edad"<<endl;
        cin>>A;
        newlista.insertar(A);
        newlista.mostrar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```